# Change VisualStudio Auto-generated Code

Tags: visual-studio, data-binding, windows-forms-designer, auto-generate

I have created myself a new TextBox control which inherits from the default System TextBox. If I add a datasource to my designer and in the DataSource view I can see my new text control in the list of controls I can drag onto the designer.

My Issue is when I drag the control onto the designer VS goes and creates the following code.

```
this.someValueTextEdit1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("EditValue", this.myViewModelBindingSource, "SomeValue", true));
```

I instead would like it to use some custom code when I drag the control onto the designer.

If your wondering why I want to do this, is so I can change the binding so that it uses linq and expression trees rather than string property values. Something like

```
Bind(this.someValueTextEdit, c => c.EditValue, v => v.SomeValue);
```

Comment: Why?  There's no point, it doesn't make it any faster.  Serializing it is painful enough, writing the code parser that reads that back is going to kill you.

Comment: I know it doesn't make it faster, it does make it strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

You shuld create your own CodeDomSerializer class.

Sample of usage: [CodeDomSerializer Class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer.aspx)